# Default font in 2012?

Tags: fonts

I have no idea if I'm using 'gutenberg' or whatever. I'm simply trying to set a default fond in 2012 classic editor so I don't have to change every paragraph I type in which is ridiculous. I see no easy/obvious way to do this. thx.

Comment: As user3135691 is alluding to if you'd prefer a different default font you probably ought to change the default font in your theme rather than for every paragraph in every article you write. That may mean editing your theme, which means creating a child theme if you're using a theme you didn't write (you're using the twentytwelve theme?) to contain the CSS override so that it won't get lost when you update the main theme.

Answer (score 1):

Easest way without investing too much effort and not worrying about coding ethics (like clean code and so on) you could simply use the "Customizer".

In your frontend, click on the "Customizer" in the upper left corner in the admin bar.
Then, scroll/go to the "Additional CSS" section and add

```
body {
    font-family: yourFontFamily!important;
}
```

to the customizer.
It will overwrite existing rules, unless each paragraph has explicitly set a custom font family. In that case this solution won't work.

Otherwise, adding this to the customizer should do the trick.
It's quick - and it's dirty.